# binding.list.addAll() not working for databinding, also used binding.executePendingBindings() , but ui not updated

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding

I am new to databinding. My exmple is simple, i am adding some static data in recyclerview, and after some time on button click, i am adding some other data in recyclerview,

so, first time for list size 0, it works fine, for second time adding data,i have used `addAll()` with `executePendingBindings()`, but it won't reflect new data in ui.

```
if(binding.list?.size==0){ 
binding.list = it 
}else{ 
binding.list?.addAll(it) 
}
binding.executePendingBindings()
```

So, But If i use , this works fine without `executePendingBinding()`

```
if(binding.list?.size==0){
binding.list = it
}else{
var old_newdata:ArrayList<Person> = (binding?.list!!+it) as ArrayList<Person>
binding.list = old_newdata
}
```

Why is that? I don't understand that why not working with addAll() and executependingbinding()?

**MainActivity.kt:**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), ListActionHandler {
    
        private val binding by lazy { ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater) }
        private lateinit var viewModel: MainViewModel
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(binding.root)
    
            viewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(MainViewModel::class.java)
    
            binding.viewModel = viewModel
            binding.list = ArrayList()
            binding.itemclickHandler = this
            startObserving()
        }
    
        private fun startObserving() {
            Handler().postDelayed(Runnable {
    
                var mutableList = ArrayList<Person>()
    
                mutableList.add(Person("Mansi Shah", "User001", 0, ""))
                mutableList.add(Person("Muuni Shah", "User002", 1, ""))
                mutableList.add(Person("Alpa Shah", "User003", 0, ""))
                mutableList.add(Person("Solani Shah", "User004", 1, ""))
                mutableList.add(Person("Menka Shah", "User005", 0, ""))
                mutableList.add(Person("Misri Shah", "User006", 0, ""))
                mutableList.add(Person("Moti Shah", "User007", 1, ""))
                mutableList.add(Person("Khevana Shah", "User008", 1, ""))
    
                //binding.list?.addAll(mutableList)
                viewModel.setListData(mutableList)
    
            }, 10000)
    
            viewModel.mutablelistData?.observe(this, Observer {
    
                it?.let {
                    //binding.list = it
                    if (binding.list?.size == 0) {
                        binding.list = it
                    } else {
                        // todo: working without execute binding and without addAll, but with =
                        // var old_newdata:ArrayList<Person> = (binding?.list!!+it) as ArrayList<Person>
                        //  binding.list = old_newdata
    
                        //todo : Not working with execute binding , so need to notify adapter
                        //binding.list?.addAll(it)
                        //binding.executePendingBindings()
    
                        val startposition = binding.list!!.size
                        binding.list?.addAll(it)
                        binding.rvPerson.adapter?.notifyItemRangeChanged(startposition, it.size)
    
                    }
    
                }
            })
        }
    
        override fun btnClick(position: Int) {
            val item = binding.list?.get(position)
    
            item?.let {
    
                when (item.follow_status) {
                    0 -> {
                        val item1 = binding.list?.get(position)?.copy(follow_status = 1)
                        viewModel.mutablelistData.value?.set(position, item1!!)
                        binding.rvPerson.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(position, item1!!)
                        //binding.rvPerson.adapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()
                    }
                    1 -> {
                        val item1 = binding.list?.get(position)?.copy(follow_status = 0)
                        viewModel.mutablelistData.value?.set(position, item1!!)
                        binding.rvPerson.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(position, item1!!)
                        // viewModel.mutablelistData.value?.set(position, item1!!)
                    }
                    else -> {
                        val item1 = binding.list?.get(position)?.copy(follow_status = 0)
                        viewModel.mutablelistData.value?.set(position, item1!!)
                        binding.rvPerson.adapter?.notifyItemChanged(position, item1!!)
                        // viewModel.mutablelistData.value?.set(position, item1!!)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        override fun btnAddClick() {
            var mutableList = ArrayList<Person>()
    
            mutableList.add(Person("Denma Shah", "User009", 0, ""))
            mutableList.add(Person("Irish Shah", "User0010", 1, ""))
            mutableList.add(Person("Mangolia Shah", "User0011", 0, ""))
            mutableList.add(Person("Lily Shah", "User0012", 1, ""))
            mutableList.add(Person("Bloom Shah", "User0013", 0, ""))
            mutableList.add(Person("Iva Shah", "User0014", 0, ""))
            mutableList.add(Person("Ishika Shah", "User0015", 1, ""))
            mutableList.add(Person("Oliver Shah", "User0016", 1, ""))
    
            //old data
            // mutableList.addAll(viewModel.getListData())
            viewModel.setListData(mutableList)
        }
    }
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <import type="java.util.ArrayList"/>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.databindingdemo.viewmodel.MainViewModel" />

        <variable
            name="list"
            type="ArrayList&lt;com.example.databindingdemo.model.Person&gt;" />

        <variable
            name="itemclickHandler"
            type="com.example.databindingdemo.actionhandler.ListActionHandler" />

    </data>


    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnAdd"
            style="@style/buttonTheme"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:onClick="@{(v)->itemclickHandler.btnAddClick()}"
            android:text="ADD"/>


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnNext"
            style="@style/buttonTheme"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:text="Next"/>
        
        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/rvPerson"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnAdd"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            bind:list="@{list}"
            bind:clickHandler="@{itemclickHandler}"
            android:visibility="@{list!=null &amp;&amp; list.size()>0? View.VISIBLE:View.GONE}"
            app:layoutManager="androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/no_data"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="No Data in List !!!"
            android:visibility="@{list!=null &amp;&amp; list.size()>0? View.GONE:View.VISIBLE}"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

**ListDataAdpater.kt :**

```
class ListDataAdpater(
    private val listData: ArrayList<Person>,
    private val clickHandler: ListActionHandler
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ListDataAdpater.ViewHolder>() {

    private var binding: ListItemDataBinding? = null

    inner class ViewHolder(val binding: ListItemDataBinding) :
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root) {

        init {
            setIsRecyclable(true)
        }

        fun bind(data: Person) {
            binding?.listItemData = data
            binding?.clickHandler = clickHandler
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        binding = ListItemDataBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(parent.context), parent, false)
        return ViewHolder(binding!!)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(listData[position])
        holder.binding.position = position
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return listData.size
    }
}
```

**list_item.xml :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:bind="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data>

        <import type="android.view.View" />

        <variable
            name="listItemData"
            type="com.example.databindingdemo.model.Person" />

        <variable
            name="clickHandler"
            type="com.example.databindingdemo.actionhandler.ListActionHandler" />

        <variable
            name="position"
            type="int" />

    </data>

    <!--  <LinearLayout
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="@dimen/_10sdp"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:visibility="gone"/>-->

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@android:color/black"
        android:padding="@dimen/_2sdp">


        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/imgUserSeach"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/_58sdp"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_58sdp"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            bind:roundedCornersRad="@{`3`}"
            bind:url="@{listItemData==null?``:listItemData.url}" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingStart="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:paddingEnd="@dimen/_5sdp"
            android:weightSum="3"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/imgUserSeach"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="2">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tvUserName"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.02"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="8sp"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:text="@{listItemData.full_name}"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:textSize="13.3sp"
                    tools:text="Mansi Shah" />

                <!-- android:onClick="@{(v)->searchItemHandler.onItemClick(searchData)}"-->

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvUserName"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_8sdp"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_medium"
                    android:letterSpacing="0.02"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="11.3sp"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:text="@{listItemData.username}"
                    android:textColor="#80ffffff"
                    android:textSize="10sp"
                    tools:text="User001" />

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/tvUserName"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

            </RelativeLayout>

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:layout_weight="1">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                    android:id="@+id/btnFollow"
                    style="@style/buttonTheme"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                    android:background="@{listItemData.follow_status == 0?@drawable/cyan_button: @drawable/grey_button}"
                    android:ellipsize="end"
                    android:lineSpacingExtra="4.5sp"
                    android:lines="1"
                    android:onClick="@{(v)->clickHandler.btnClick(position)}"
                    android:text="@{listItemData.follow_status == 0? @string/follow : @string/following}" />
            </RelativeLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/vdivider"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_1sdp"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/_10sdp"
            android:background="#8b9096"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/imgUserSeach" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>
```

**BindAdapters.kt :**

```
@JvmStatic // add this line !!
        @BindingAdapter(value = ["bind:list", "bind:clickHandler"], requireAll = false)
        fun bindAdapter(view: RecyclerView, list: ArrayList<Person>?, handler: ListActionHandler) {

            list?.let {
                val adapter = ListDataAdpater(list, handler)
                view.adapter = adapter
            }
        }
```

Comment: Can you give more information?. Where does this code live? In an Activity, in an Adapter? How is `list` used in the layout?

Comment: @Entreco, code added, and above snippet code is in activity inside startObserving() method